# Supervisor restarting python app on GPIO event detect

Tags: rpi.gpio

I'm using supervisor to monitor a long running gunicorn/flask process on my pi that monitors my garage door with a reed switch on a GPIO pin and GPIO.add_event_detect.

The problem is every time the door opens or closes supervisor sends SIGTERM to the app and restarts it.

If I run the app as a daemon process without supervisor it works fine, had no issues for over a week now.

Anyone else had an issue like this before?

Comment: do you know what are the odds of somebody else having the same hardware and same software as you?

Comment: Since I posted this in the raspberry pi section I figured hardware would be quite common.. and I'm pretty sure many people use the gpio library on them...

Comment: i wasn't talking about the RPI when i said hardware